# Error IDX10500 with Azure AD B2C CustomPolicy

Tags: .net, blazor, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm trying to handle the `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp` in .NET 8 (Blazor Web App) with Azure AD B2C.
I have some CustomPolicy that should be okay. But after clicking local account login, I got the following error.

> IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature.

Where can i add/find this security key or what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your Authority is configured as something like:

```
https://yourb2ctenant.b2clogin.com/yourb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_YOUR_CUSTOM_POLICY/v2.0
```

This leads to it downloading OpenID configuration from:

```
https://yourb2ctenant.b2clogin.com/yourb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_YOUR_CUSTOM_POLICY/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

That document contains the `jwks_uri` where the signing keys are.
Typically the libraries should handle all this for you.
I don't have time right now to check how exactly that API works that you are using.
But ultimately the above is what it needs to end up at.